# Symbol "|" in dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What does symbol **|** mean in dependency list, e.g.

```
foobar: foo | bar
  do_something ....
```

Where *foo* and *bar* are targets generated by makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the section on [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) in the GNU make manual.

Basically this means that `bar` must be built before `foobar`, but that `foobar` won't be considered out of date because `bar` is newer than `foobar`.